# Am I Oversimplifying Calculating Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm just trying to calculate complexity on some program fragments, but I'm, worried I'm making things too simple. If I put my fragments and answers down, can you tell me if I'm doing anything wrong with it?

(a)

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    sum++;
```

ANSWER: n, only one for loop

(b)

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    for (k = 0;k < n*n;k++)
        sum++;
```

ANSWER: n^2 because of the nested loop, although I wonder if the n*n in the nested loop makes it n^3

(c)

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    for (k = 0;k < i;k++)
        sum++;
```

ANSWER: n^2

(d)

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    for (k = 0;k < i*i;k++)
        sum++;
```

ANSWER: n^2, but I have the same concern as b

(e)

```
sum= 0;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    for (k = i;k < n;k++)
        sum++;
```

ANSWER: n^2

Comment: *Am I oversimplifying* - yes, because merely counting the number of for loops is a common beginner mistake. And your concerns about b) and d) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since in all your examples the main operation is `sum++`, we are bound to count the number of times this basic operation is performed.

Also, in all cases, there is the `i++` operation, that also counts, as well as the `k++`. Finally, these counters have to be compared with their limits at every step, and we should also take these comparisons into account. Now, these additional operations don't change the number of iterations; they simply make each iteration more expensive. For instance,

(a)

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
  sum++;
```

repeats `n` times: `i++`, `sum++` and `i<n`, all of which gives `3n` operations of similar complexity. This is why the total complexity is `O(n)`.

Once this has been understood, it is no longer necessary to analyze the complexity in as much detail, because the big-O notation will take care of these additional calculations.

The second example

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
  for (k = 0;k < n*n;k++)
    sum++;
```

repeats `n` time the operation

```
  for (k = 0;k < n*n;k++)
    sum++;
```

Because of the previous case, this operation has complexity `O(n*n)` as here the limit is `n*n` rather than `n`. Thus the total complexity is `O(n*n*n)`.

The third example is similar, except that this time the operation being executed `n` times is

```
for (k = 0;k < i;k++)
    sum++;
```

which has a complexity that changes with `i`. Therefore, instead of multiplying by `n` we have to sum `n` different things:

```
O(1) + O(2) + ... + O(n)
```

and since the constant factor implicit in the `O` is always the same (= number of variables being increased or compared at every elementary step), we can rewrite it as

```
O(1 + 2 + ... + n) = O(n(n+1)/2) = O(n*n)
```

The other examples are similar in that they can be analyzed following these very same ideas.